# Extension method doesnt work?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, extension-methods

I'm trying to use

```
public static string TryGetRequestValue(this HttpRequest stringArg, int maxLengthArg)
{
    return null;
}
```

As an extension method and it isn't working I get the error message 'No overload for method TryGetRequestValue' etc etc...

However when I take out the HttpRequest arg and change it to a string it works....Why is this?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The key is in how you're **using** it. Please post the code by which you *call* the method, and the rest of the error message as well. That'll make it much easier to figure out what's going wrong! :)

Comment: Could you show how are you trying to call this extension method?

Comment: Also what is signature of a class of your method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my comment under the question, but based on this statement:

> However when I take out the
>   HttpRequest arg and change it to a
>   string it works....Why is this?

The first parameter in an extension method - the one prefixed with `this` - determines the type being extended. So the expected way to call this method would be:

```
HttpRequest instanceOfClassBeingExtended = new HttpRequest();
string returnValue = instanceOfClassBeingExtended.TryGetRequestValue(10000);
```

The method returns a `string`, and only takes *one* parameter: `maxLengthArg`.

Apologies if you already know this much - posting the code that's throwing the exception, as well as the exception itself, will make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Because the **Params** collection of the **HttpRequest** object is a collection of the type **NameValueCollection** you can not directly check for the existence of some key. But this class has the **AllKeys** property that return an array of keys the you can use *Linq* to check the key existence and get the value by means of the **Get()** Method:

```
public static string TryGetRequestValue(this HttpRequest request, string stringArg)
{
    string result = null;
    string[] keys = request.Params.AllKeys;
    if( keys.Contains<string>(stringArg) )
    {
        result = request.Params.Get(stringArg);
    }   
    return result;
}
```

Then you can invoke the method as follows:

```
Request.TryGetRequestValue("someGetParam");
```